# When using a DI framework, how does a new service know what other services are available?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

In a large project that is using a DI framework (such as Ninject in my case), what options exist when implementing a new "service" to find out what other "services" are available to be used as dependencies. Before using DI I have noticed a tendency in our code base to get a reference to a "god" object that pretty much gave access to all the available functionality and then Visual Studio's IntelliSense would become very helpful to discover what all was available (obviously this approach was only possible because of poor architectural decisions of having such an object in the first place).

I can some possible answers and am interested what has worked for others:

1. You should know the overall system you are working in well enough
   to know what other classes/services exist (for example, if I had
   static classes I would just have to know that they exist to be able
   to use them).
2. You maintain good external documentation of your
   code base so all classes/services are understand by all developers
   (this imposes a large documentation burden, it would seem to me).
3. Create an API to query the DI container (Ninject kernel) for a list
   of all bindings to see what services are available (perhaps only
   Singletons). This could also be done as part of the build system to
   generate a document automatically upon each build that developers
   could reference.

Has this ever been an issue for other developers?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't want to see all services exist in a system and then choose one of them. You want to access a functionallity. Structure your classes with namespaces in a way so that it is obvious where to look for it.

E.g. If I want to know what collections are available in .NET I type `System.Collections.Generic.` and the IntelliSense gives me a list of options.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to organise my codebase so that I have a central 'Interface' project to which all other projects have a reference. Then my `Logger` is available only through the `ILogger` interface, and the logging module can choose which concrete `ILogger` to provide. You should not be requesting concrete classes - this defeats the purpose of DI.

In general when you are implementing a new service you should **already know** what dependencies you need. If you don't know what you should use, **ask someone who does.** This is the equivalent to having adequate documentation - relying on intellisense will give you a very shallow idea of what you should take as a dependency. Instead you should consult either the documentation or someone who understands the area.